# Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned

Tags: symfony, doctrine, composer-php

I get this warning when I  run `composer update` :

> Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use roave/better-reflection instead.

I tried to add roave/better-reflection instead and remove doctrine/reflection without success.
I'm on Symfony 5.2 but I already had the warning with Symfony 5.1.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's just a warning, likely triggered by one of your own doctrine dependencies. There is nothing to be there for you at the moment.

Comment: @yivi I have deleted my vendor folder and did a `composer install` to be sure, but the message comes back anyway.

Comment: And it will keep coming back. Again, nothing for you to do here. It's just a warning anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For average symfony users, this is an **internal warning** coming directly from doctrine's *own* dependencies, see:

```
vendor/doctrine/common/composer.json
vendor/doctrine/persistence/composer.json
```

Where they have `"doctrine/reflection": "^1.0"` in their composer.json files.

They'll likely do something about this in a future release, so for now we must live with the warning.

**I will update my answer when there is more information**

Answer (score 7):

As you can see [on packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/reflection/dependents), there are some packages that depend on `doctrine/reflection` - the missing information here are the specific versions that require this package. Abandoning `doctrine/reflection` has (technically) happened [on Oct 29 2020](https://github.com/doctrine/reflection/pull/53), so it's not surprising that not all depending packages were updated.

After all, this is not a red flag for you. If you were depending directly on this package, you should act and replace it. Others have already done so, like [`doctrine/common`](https://github.com/doctrine/common/pull/893) or [`symfony/symfony`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/38870), or might do so in future versions.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @YesBarry please share more details - which parts of my answer do look wrong for you? As fas as I can see, your own answer does not contain anything else than "This is only a warning, nothing serious"

Comment: Nothing is wrong, it just didn't answer the question for symfony users. Your answer looks to be better suited for the actual developers at symfony, but I'm sure they already are aware of these details.